# Por que mesmo com margin 0 e padding 0 ainda existe espaço entre os elementos?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho 3 botões um do lado do outro e queria que ficassem com 1px de margin apenas entre eles mas ta ficando muito mais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O html:

```
<div class="popup">
    <p id="popupText">TRUCO!</p>
    <div class="popup-buttons">
        <button>SIM</button>
        <button class="truco">SEIS!</button>
        <button>NÃO</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui o css:

```
* {
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
button {
    background: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 24px "Alfa Slab One", cursive;
    margin: 1px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
    width: 150px;
}
.truco {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é apenas a maneira como os elementos `inline-block` se comportam.
Estes espaçamentos são o mesmo que espaçamentos entre palavras. Se colocarmos os elementos todos juntos (palavras todas juntas) não iremos ter nenhum espaço entre os elementos.

> Quebras de linha também contam como espaçamento entre os elementos `inline-block`.

Dito isto, se removermos os espaços (quebras de linhas) entre os botões, este comportamento irá desaparecer:

```css
* {
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
button {
    background: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 24px "Alfa Slab One", cursive;
    margin: 1px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
    width: 150px;
}
.truco {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sem quebras de linha -->
<div class="popup">
    <p id="popupText">TRUCO!</p>
    <div class="popup-buttons">
        <button>SIM</button><button class="truco">SEIS!</button><button>NÃO</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Com quebras de linha -->
<div class="popup">
    <p id="popupText-2">TRUCO 2!</p>
    <div class="popup-buttons">
        <button>SIM</button>
        <button class="truco">SEIS!</button>
        <button>NÃO</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Existem também outras maneiras de remover estes espaços, como adicionar uma margem negativa aos elementos onde a propriedade `inline-block` foi aplicada, entre outros métodos. Podes ler este artigo que eu criei sobre este tópico há uns anos atrás neste link: [Estranho espaçamento entre elementos inline-block](https://tedcss.blogspot.pt/2015/07/estranho-espacamento-entre-elementos-inline-block.html)